# Prevent Excel pop up message in VB code

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am having a problem with the "File Now Available" message box popping open from excel when i importing a file to my program.

http://oi50.tinypic.com/23wajt.jpg

```
Private Function XLSSelect_Click(strFileName As String) As DataTable

    Dim connectionStringTemplate As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source={0};" + "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
    Dim connectionString As String = String.Format(connectionStringTemplate, strFileName)

    Try
        Dim sqlSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & GetExcelSheetNames(strFileName)(0) & "];"
        ' Load the Excel worksheet into a DataTable
        Dim workbook As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim excelAdapter As System.Data.Common.DataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSelect, connectionString)
        excelAdapter.Fill(workbook)

        For i As Integer = 0 To workbook.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            workbook.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName = workbook.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString.Trim.Replace(" ", "")
        Next

        Return workbook.Tables(0).Copy
    Catch
        Throw New Exception("Error reading from Excel Spreadsheet. Are you sure this file isn't currently open in Excel, and that it has been saved as a .xls through Excel at least once?")
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Shared Function GetExcelSheetNames(excelFile As String) As [String]()
    Dim objConn As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = Nothing

    Try
        Dim connString As [String] = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & excelFile & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
        ' Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
        objConn = New OleDbConnection(connString)

        ' Open connection with the database.
        objConn.Open()
        ' Get the data table containg the schema guid.
        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

        If dt Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim excelSheets As [String]() = New [String](dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        'Add the sheet name to the string array.
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            excelSheets(i) = row("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            i += 1
        Next

        Return excelSheets
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        ' Clean up.
        If objConn IsNot Nothing Then
            objConn.Close()
            objConn.Dispose()
        End If
        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            dt.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Anyone know how i can go about disabling this ?

Comment: Are you open the EXCEL first before run the program?

Comment: The excel file has been opened a few times and worked with before running it in the program. but it is not open at the time the program is run.

Comment: Xnub: Can you make sure that it is not open (Check task Manager)

Comment: And if there is no Excel file in Memory then try adding `GC.Collect()` in the final clean up of your code so that Excel is released when you run the code next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application

Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
appExcel.Workbooks.Open "e:\development\test.xls", 0

'  Do your thing here...

appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False  '  Surpress save dialog box.
appExcel.Quit  '  Quit without saving. you can change as you want
Set appExcel = Nothing
```

in your code

```
Try
        Dim connString As [String] = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & excelFile & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
        ' Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
        objConn = New OleDbConnection(connString)

        ' Open connection with the database.
        objConn.Open()
```

appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False  ' try here!

```
        ' Get the data table containg the schema guid.
        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
```

Sources : http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=16007

Comment: look at below code, i have adapt it to you,, just need to insert 1 line >>> appexcel.displayalerts = false<<< after your connection.open

Comment: appexcel variable is not anywhere in my code and using any other of the variables won't work as they are database connections etc and don't recognize the `.displayalerts = false`

Comment: How about you setting the code i give it to you on the excel open form.. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=58990